# Как изменить название кнопки при нажатии?

Tags: jquery, css3, html5

Всем привет! Как изменить название кнопки при её нажатии, например 'Open' менялось на 'Close'.

```js
$('.text__footer').on('click', '#btm', function(){
 $(this).parents().siblings();
 $(this).parents().toggleClass('hfooter', );
 $(this).parents('.text-footer__about').find('p').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```css
.text__footer {
 height: 175px;
 border: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
 background-color: #fff;
  width: 370px;
  background-color: #FBFAF8;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: 2s;
}

.text-footer__about h6 {
 color: #555;
}

.text-footer__about span {
 color: #8c8c8c;
}

.hfooter {
 height: 300px;
}

#btm {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text__footer">
     <div class="text-footer__about">
      <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h6>
      <span>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.</span>
      <p style="display: none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis deserunt quia voluptatibus rerum vero voluptate recusandae, assumenda eos voluptates odio, asperiores magnam aut commodi alias, quibusdam consectetur. Vitae earum, nisi.</p>
      <button id="btm">Open</button>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.text__footer').on('click', '#btm', function() {
  $(this).parents().siblings();
  //$(this).parents().toggleClass('hfooter', );
  $(this).parents('.text-footer__about').find('p').slideToggle(1000);

  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    return text === "Open" ? "Close" : "Open";
  });
});
```

```css
.text__footer {
  height: 175px;
  border: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 370px;
  background-color: #FBFAF8;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: 2s;
}

.text-footer__about h6 {
  color: #555;
}

.text-footer__about span {
  color: #8c8c8c;
}

.hfooter {
  height: 300px;
}

#btm {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text__footer">
  <div class="text-footer__about">
    <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h6>
    <span>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.</span>
    <p style="display: none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis deserunt quia voluptatibus rerum vero voluptate recusandae, assumenda eos voluptates odio, asperiores magnam aut commodi alias, quibusdam consectetur. Vitae earum, nisi.</p>
    <button id="btm">Open</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var isOpen = true;
$('.text__footer').on('click', '#btm', function(){
 $(this).parents().siblings();
 $(this).parents().toggleClass('hfooter', );
 $(this).parents('.text-footer__about').find('p').slideToggle(1000);
    if(isOpen){
        $(this).text('Close');
        isOpen = false;
    }else{
        $(this).text('Open');
        isOpen = true;
    }
});
```

```css
.text__footer {
 height: 175px;
 border: 2px solid #F8F8F8;
 background-color: #fff;
  width: 370px;
  background-color: #FBFAF8;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  transition: 2s;
}

.text-footer__about h6 {
 color: #555;
}

.text-footer__about span {
 color: #8c8c8c;
}

.hfooter {
 height: 300px;
}

#btm {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text__footer">
     <div class="text-footer__about">
      <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h6>
      <span>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium.</span>
      <p style="display: none;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis deserunt quia voluptatibus rerum vero voluptate recusandae, assumenda eos voluptates odio, asperiores magnam aut commodi alias, quibusdam consectetur. Vitae earum, nisi.</p>
      <button id="btm">Open</button>
     </div>
    </div>
```